# SpringBoot configurate two jndi data sources

Tags: spring-boot

I use springboot to configure two datasources.
First:

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource_app")
    public DataSource appDataSource(){
            if(config.getJndiName()!=null){
        JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new   JndiDataSourceLookup();
        dataSourceLookup.setResourceRef(true);
        return dataSourceLookup.getDataSource(config.getJndiName());
    }
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
```

Second one

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource_domain")
public DataSource domainDataSource(){
    if(config.getJndiName()!=null){
        JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        return dataSourceLookup.getDataSource(config.getJndiName());
    }
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
```

}

But when i run application i get this exception:

```
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: Catalina:type=DataSource,host=localhost,context=/dir-master,class=javax.sql.DataSource,name="jdbc/dir"
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
at org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanRegistrationSupport.doRegister(MBeanRegistrationSupport.java:195)
at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanInstance(MBeanExporter.java:670)
at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:615)
... 25 more
```

What am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Spring Boot will attempt to register with JMX any beans in the application context that are MBeans. That causes a problem here as Tomcat has already registered the JNDI DataSource as an MBean.

Spring Boot's own `JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration` avoids the problem by telling the application context's `MBeanExporter` to not export the MBean:

```
private void excludeMBeanIfNecessary(Object candidate, String beanName) {
    try {
        MBeanExporter mbeanExporter = this.context.getBean(MBeanExporter.class);
        if (JmxUtils.isMBean(candidate.getClass())) {
            mbeanExporter.addExcludedBean(beanName);
        }
    }
    catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException ex) {
        // No exporter. Exclusion is unnecessary
    }
}
```

You can avoid the problem by doing similar in your own configuration class.